# V-Select displaying entire array on one selection

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have created an object that has both countries and values for these countries, I wish to display each country in the array with its corresponding value from another array withing the object. The problem is, all values from the displayed array are output on one selection line of the v-select.

I have put both arrays into an object and set the items to my object and then setting item-text to the countries array and the item-value to the countries corresponding values array.

```
getCountries() {
      let services = this.$store.state.services;
      let countries = {};
      let names = ['china','usa','malaysia','philippines','cambodia','myanmar','vietnam','indonesia','brazil','south_africa','united_kingdom','morocco','hong_kong','macau'];
      let prices = [];
      services.forEach(element => {
        if (element['service'] == this.selectedService) {
          names.forEach(country => {
            if (element[country] !== null) {
              prices.push(element[country]);
            }
          })
        }
      });

      countries.name = names;
      countries.price = prices;
      console.log(countries)

      return countries;

    },
```

```
<v-select
    v-model="selectedCountry"
    v-validate="'required'"
    :items="getCountries"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="price"
    label="Select Country"
    prepend-icon="filter_list"
    required
></v-select>
```

The V-Select should be like so:

```
china
usa
malaysia
...
```

but instead it shows as:

```
china,usa,malaysia
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for myself. Made it a hell of a lot easier putting objects into an array with my data. :)

```
    getCountries() {
  let services = this.$store.state.services;
  let names = ['china','usa','malaysia','philippines','cambodia','myanmar','vietnam','indonesia','brazil','south_africa','united_kingdom','morocco','hong_kong','macau'];
  let prices = [];
  let x = {};
  let y = []
  services.forEach(element => {
    if (element['service'] == this.selectedService) {
      names.forEach(country => {
        if (element[country] !== null) {
          x[country] = element[country];
          y.push({name: country, price: element[country]})

        }
      })
    }
  });
  console.log(y)
  return y;

},
```